# dpkg --configure -a not working

Tags: debian, dpkg

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up sandboxgamemaker (2.7.1+dfsg-2) ...
Cleaned old data
--2013-11-01 18:28:33--  http://sandboxgamemaker.com/sandbox/PlatinumArtsSandbox
2.7.1Multiplatfrom.zip
Resolving sandboxgamemaker.com (sandboxgamemaker.com)... 173.236.241.215
Connecting to sandboxgamemaker.com (sandboxgamemaker.com)|173.236.241.215|:80...
 connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.sandboxgamemaker.com/sandbox/PlatinumArtsSandbox2.7.1Multip
latfrom.zip [following]
--2013-11-01 18:28:34--  http://www.sandboxgamemaker.com/sandbox/PlatinumArtsSan
dbox2.7.1Multiplatform.zip
Resolving www.sandboxgamemaker.com (www.sandboxgamemaker.com)... 173.236.241.215
Reusing existing connection to sandboxgamemaker.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Length: 445937900 (425M), 283579684 (270M) remaining [application/zip]
Saving to: `PlatinumArtsSandbox2.7.1Multiplatform.zip'

36% [+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                                                                 ] 16,31,95,440 66.7K/s  eta 70m 55s
```

This command has been running for 1 hour and it is still not repaired.

I use Debian 7.

Comment: The connection speed looks slow, which is why it is taking so so long.  No big deal.

Comment: In the lower right hand corner, the ETA or estimated time to completion shows 70 minutes 55 seconds.  I would only be concerned if this number is frozen and never goes down.

Comment: @Lumberjack no its not stuck. but i am using broadband at a speed of 512 kbps. what to do now?

Comment: @goldilocks what to do now? my broadban speed is low!

Comment: @Lumberjack what to do now? how can i cancel it?

Comment: @Utkarsh you could remove sandboxgamemaker.

Comment: but how?tell some command i am just 13 year old and not know anything @jordanm

Comment: You might as well wait for it now.  You don't have to remove `sandboxgamemaker` *unless* it continues to be a pain this way, but hopefully this will only happen once.  The issue is it's huge, and perhaps it is their server (sandboxgamemaker.com) that is slow.

Comment: @goldilocks why dont you post this as an answer, i think, its the best answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's running correctly.

Once a `deb` package get installed, a post installation script get executed. In this case, it tries to download something from the internet. So you need to wait until it finishes, and see if anything else goes wrong. Otherwise it's just fine.

Comment: The only other thing you could try is changing your mirrors. [see here](http://www.debian.org/mirror/official). But honestly, that probably won't work as your taking forever to download "Sand Box Game Maker" and that's not coming from a Debian mirror.

Comment: okay so i waited and it worked! thnx